# USER_PRESENT with AppWidgetProvider in Android Oreo 8 not received

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, appwidgetprovider

I'm creating an Android Widget and are trying to receive the USER_PRESENT intent that I have registered in my AndroidManifest.xml. When the user unlocks their phone the widget should fetch and update itself with weather information I fetch from a backend. But i'm not receiving it on my Android 8 device. From what I read this is no longer supported?

I do it like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".AppWidgetProvider" android:label="@string/widget_name_4_2">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
    android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

And in my AppWidgetProvider

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    Log.w("log", "onReceive " + intent.getAction());
}
```

What is the alternatives to catch this intent? Foreground service? Something else? Is it even possible now days?

Comment: Those implicit broadcasts registered in the manifest are not delivered any more (with a few exceptions that can be found in the android docs). You need to register for broadcasts programmatically, but there's also restrictions on this (e.g. you cannot do it from a broadcastreceiver context, need to use context.getApplicationContext()). I got a similar problem and I'm still trying to figure out a solution. Will let you know when I did.

Comment: I also tried that and then recevied the broadcast, but the solution feels very fragile. I had problems to unregister it as well. I will continue the search as well :)

Comment: did you find anything as a solution?

Comment: Any solution???

Comment: No solution sorry and i've left the project due to new work :(